Reference parameters from template file in Azure pipeline
I have an azurePipeline that have some parameters defined in a template file called
alerts-parameters.yml
parameters:
  - name: alerts
    type: object
    default: 
      - alertName: 'ex1'
        alertParam: '1'
      - alertName: 'ex2'
        alertParam: '2'
      - alertName: 'ex3'
        alertParam: '3'


In the pipeline I am defining the parameters as template under variables and iterating on those parameters and execute simple pipeline but it's not able to identify the alerts to iterate on it.
azurePipeline.yml
variables:
  - template: alerts-parameters.yml


jobs:
  - job: ValidateAlert
    displayName: 'ValidateAlert'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
    - ${{ each alert in parameters.alerts }}:
      - task: AzureCLI@2
        displayName: 'Validate Alert: ${{ alert.alertName }}'
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: $(ResourceGroup)
          scriptType: 'bash'
          scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
          inlineScript: |
            echo "Validating alert: ${{ alert.alertName }}"


Azure pipeline error
/azurePipeline.yml (Line: 10, Col: 7): Key not found 'alerts'
N.B: It works if the parameters are defined in the same AzurePiplien file but I am trying to add those parameters in another template file as they are huge (this is simplified example)
Working Example:
parameters:
  - name: alerts
    type: object
    default: 
      - alertName: 'ex1'
        alertParam: '1'
      - alertName: 'ex2'
        alertParam: '2'
      - alertName: 'ex3'
        alertParam: '3'

jobs:
  - job: ValidateAlert
    displayName: 'ValidateAlert'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
    - ${{ each alert in parameters.alerts }}:
      - task: AzureCLI@2
        displayName: 'Validate Alert: ${{ alert.alertName }}'
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: $(ResourceGroup)
          scriptType: 'bash'
          scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
          inlineScript: |
            echo "Validating alert: ${{ alert.alertName }}"



Why does it matter if the list is large? Extracting it into a separate file won't make it any less large, it will just hide that it's large, the same way collapsing a section of YAML in your editor will hide that something is large. Sometimes the correct answer to stuff like this is "Yeah, it's a big list. So what?"

@DanielMann Yes but I need to separate them as this will be used by multiple teams, so each team can include their parameters file directly and use the same pipeline, I don't want them to change the pipeline but just refer to their parameters file location

It is not possible to reuse parameters. Templates allow the reuse of variables, steps, jobs and stages.
See Templates usage reference for more details.
EDIT
If each team can create one or more dedicated pipelines, consider providing a base pipeline (using extends templates) or another template that can be easily reused in different pipelines.
Example:
# base-pipeline.yaml

parameters:
  # an object containing the following properties:
  # - name: The name of the alert
  # - displayName: The display name of the alert
  # - param: The parameter of the alert
  - name: alerts
    displayName: 'Alerts'
    type: object

stages:
  - ${{ each alert in parameters.alerts }}:
    - stage: ${{ alert.name }}
      displayName: ${{ alert.displayName }}
      dependsOn: []
      jobs:
        - job: job_${{ alert.name }}
          displayName: ${{ alert.displayName }}
          steps:
            - checkout: none
            - script: |
                echo "${{ alert.name }} - ${{ alert.param }}"
              displayName: 'Run ${{ alert.name }} - ${{ alert.param }}'

Sample pipeline for team A using pipeline parameters:
# Team A pipeline

parameters:
  - name: alerts
    displayName: 'Alerts'
    type: object
    default:
      - name: teamA1
        displayName: 'Team A Alert 1'
        param: '01'
      - name: teamA2
        displayName: 'Team A Alert 2'
        param: '02'

extends:
  template: base-pipeline.yaml
  parameters:
    alerts: ${{ parameters.alerts }}

Or, as an alternative:
# Team A pipeline

extends:
  template: base-pipeline.yaml
  parameters:
    alerts:
      - name: teamA1
        displayName: 'Team A Alert 1'
        param: '01'
      - name: teamA2
        displayName: 'Team A Alert 2'
        param: '02'

Variables can be used to set the alerts instead (in case the number of alerts is fixed):
# Team A pipeline

# Variables below must be declared or referenced somewhere, 
# depending on the kind of template used (extends vs other templates)

extends:
  template: base-pipeline.yaml
  parameters:
    alerts:
      - name: $(alertName1)
        displayName: 'Team A $(alertName1)'
        param:  $(alertParam1)
      - name: $(alertName2)
        displayName: 'Team A $(alertName2)'
        param:  $(alertParam2)


Downvoter care to explain the downvote?

Is there any other way, even use it as variables or any other way but most important is I want to separate them in another file

@karimSayed yes there are workarounds, but if you need to use the parameters for a specific team in 2 different places you'll have to copy/paste them. Can each team have a dedicated pipeline?

Yes it would be a reference Pipeline or repo which teams can use or call for their pipelines and add override their parameters/variables files, I tried to include them as variables but didn't accept it since it's from object type, If there is a way to include as variables template directly then that would be better

@karimSayed variables might work for simple scenarios and if you have a fixed number of parameters.

Can you please write an example how to use the variables, I checked it and seems not allowed to use objects or arrays or lists with variables only Parameters !!

@karimSayed that's correct - variables are NOT strongly-typed, they can have only simple values - that's why I mentioned variables might work for simple scenarios (and if you have a fixed number of parameters). Also, you'd still need to somehow pass the variables to the templates.

@karimSayed added some examples - solution is probably not as dynamic as you'd wish for, but you can split the big list of parameters by using multiple pipelines which should make your life easier (and other teams as well).
